# openssl s_client using a proxy

Tags: openssl

```
openssl s_client -connect some.https.server:443 -showcerts
```

is a nice command to run when you want to inspect the server's certificates and its certificate chain.

Is there a way to run this command when you are behind a HTTP/HTTPS proxy ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Officially not.

But here's a patch: http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2651&user=guest&pass=guest

Comment: It appears actually that as of May 22 2015, that patch was actually implemented.  I also see in the

Comment: Specified URL no longer work.

Answer (score 63):

You can use [proxytunnel](http://proxytunnel.sourceforge.net/):

```
proxytunnel -p yourproxy:8080 -d www.google.com:443 -a 7000
```

and then you can do this:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:7000 -showcerts
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: I had to make `proxytunnel -p yourproxy:8080 -d www.google.com:443 -a 7000` run in the background to free up the terminal for the second command.

Comment: `proxytunnel` supports proxy auth, which (afaict) `openssl s_client -proxy` doesn't, at least not in 1.1.0h.

Answer (score 58):

since openssl v1.1.0

```
C:\openssl>openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
C:\openssl>openssl s_client -proxy 192.168.103.115:3128 -connect www.google.com -CAfile C:\TEMP\internalCA.crt
CONNECTED(00000088)
depth=2 DC = com, DC = xxxx, CN = xxxx CA interne
verify return:1
depth=1 C = FR, L = CROIX, CN = svproxysg1, emailAddress = xxxx@xxxx.xx
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = www.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=xxxx/L=xxxx/CN=svproxysg1/emailAddress=xxxx@xxxx.xx
 1 s:/C=xxxx/L=xxxx/CN=svproxysg1/emailAddress=xxxx@xxxx.xx
   i:/DC=com/DC=xxxxx/CN=xxxxx CA interne
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDkTCCAnmgAwIBAgIJAIv4/hQAAAAAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMFIxCzAJBgNV
BAYTAkZSMQ4wDAYDVQQHEwVDUk9JWDETMBEGA1UEAxMKc3Zwcm94eXNnMTEeMBwG
```

Comment: Downloaded 1.1.1 source, tried this syntax. Worked perfectly. Cheers.

Comment: thanks, I have not noticed the `-proxy` option, but I wonder if instead of it, it should consider proxy envvars.

Comment: Raul, I have not find "http_proxy" in source code so I can consider proxy environment variable is not supported

Comment: unfortunately, no socks5 proxy support.

Answer (score 34):

for anyone coming here as of post-May 2015: there's a new "-proxy" option that will be included in the next release of openssl: https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2651&user=guest&pass=guest

Comment: I just tried OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016 (Windows), and it doesn't know anything about a proxy option. Why?

Comment: Is it ok to update openssl package to a version that isn't bundled with the OS?

Comment: @ChristianSchäfer It's because version 1.0.2xx is not a "next release". This option available only in OpenSSL 1.1.0xx and later.

Comment: Indeed, see manual page https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/openssl-s_client.html#OPTIONS

Comment: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-s_client.html#OPTIONS

Comment: For those needing something to cut/paste from:  `openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443 -proxy yourproxy:8080 -showcerts`

Answer (score 1):

Even with openssl v1.1.0 I had some problems passing our proxy, e.g. `s_client: HTTP CONNECT failed: 400 Bad Request` 
That forced me to write a minimal Java-class to show the SSL-Handshake

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.my.company", 8080);
    DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
            .build();
    URI uri = new URIBuilder()
            .setScheme("https")
            .setHost("www.myhost.com")
            .build();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    httpclient.execute(httpget);
}
```

With following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

you can run it with [Java SSL Logging turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659564/limiting-java-ssl-debug-logging)

This should produce nice output like

```
trustStore provider is :
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc3517
  Valid from Mon Jun 21 06:00:00 CEST 1999 until Mon Jun 22 06:00:00 CEST 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US
(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in proxy mechanism in recent versions of `openssl` supports only HTTP proxies. To proxy via a SOCKS proxy, you can use `socat`. For example, with socat 1.8 to proxy via [SOCKS5](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#ADDRESS_SOCKS5_CONNECT), you would do:

```
socat --experimental \
  TCP-LISTEN:1443,fork,reuseaddr \
  SOCKS5-CONNECT:my-proxy:1080:some.https.server:443
```

and then connect to localhost:1443:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:1443 -showcerts
```

Socat also supports [`SOCKS4`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#ADDRESS_SOCKS4) and [`SOCKS4A`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#ADDRESS_SOCKS4A).