# perl script for showing ssl certs

Tags: perl, ssl, openssl

I would like to view the `ssl` certificate of 3rd party hosts using [openssl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL), but openssl `s_client` doesn't support proxies (which I do have in my environment).

I'm hoping that I can use perl for doing the equivalent of this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.domain.com:443
```

Comment: I have searched CPAN, and looked on various google posts, but most stuff was aimed at verifying certificates.   This isn't what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to inspect the certificates and print them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search around `dump_peer_certificate()` method from `Net::SSLeay` module.

See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=70620 and http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay

Comment: Thanks to share your search : paste your code in your original POST please.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch `openssl` to accept proxys, see [openssl patch](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2651&user=guest&pass=guest) and [openssl s_client using a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220419/openssl-s-client-using-a-proxy)

Comment: Hi Sputnick, I have seen that post.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the version of openssl that is installed. :(