# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.2

Tags: java, ssl, https

Anyone knows what could be the cause of a `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.2` ?

I keep finding `* Unknown-0.0`, `* Unknown-105.113` etc. on google, what do these numbers signify ?

Comment: Which java runtime do you use?

Comment: I was running my dynamic web application on Weblogic 12 with JDK 7

Comment: Any clues found by setting system property `javax.net.debug=all` and observing stdout?

Comment: @DavidJ.Liszewski Better yet, set `javax.net.debug` to `ssl:record` (or maybe `ssl:handshake`). E.g. `javax.net.debug=ssl:record`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659564/limiting-java-ssl-debug-logging