# Java/Tomcat debugging (SSL) - which log file is used?

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, ssl, tomcat7

I'd like to add the following to the Java-OPTS of my tomcat:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

I do this because I need to debug the ssl connnections to and from said tomcat.

Questions:

- In which log file will the output of the debugging go? Catalina.out?
- Is it possible to configure which file the output should go to?
- If so, can you point me to a manual or give me an example?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

Should be `catalina.out`

You can find more options in the answer below:

[limiting java ssl debug logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659564/limiting-java-ssl-debug-logging)