# Where does debug SSL put its log?

Tags: java, debugging, ssl, logging

I'm using java to connect via SSL to API and I'm trying do understand what am I doing wrong by debugging it, but where should I look if I use only tests and not tomcat or any other application containers? Before starting doing application calls I do this to enable debug:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
```

Is there any log files in Java's library or console or what? I don't see any logs anywhere. Please help.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30104610/1790644) help?

Comment: It's outputs to the standard error stream, System.err. It's possible that setting the property inside your program is too late to affect the property. All the examples I see have it set on java launcher via something like `java  -Djavax.net.debug=ssl  ...`