# HttpMethodDirectory executeWithRetry and SSLProtocolException in Java

Tags: java, java-11, openjdk-11, sslexception

I am using httpclient-3.0 library to parse data to cloud. When I run the application on my local machine (Windows 10), it works fine and the data gets parsed to the server and I receive success response, but when I deployed it on our server which runs on Windows server 2012 R2, it throws below error. I have used the same JDK as well I tried many ways like adding -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" in my java.security jdk file, but still the issue is not resolved.

### **Here is my code**

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(apiUrl);
post.setParameter("authtoken", authToken);
post.setParameter("dateFormat", dateTimeFormat);
post.setParameter("data", emloyeesAttendanceJsonArr.toString());
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
// Configuring proxy
httpclient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("**.**.**.**", ****);
try {
    long timeTrace = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);
    System.out.println(">> HTTP Response status code: "+result);
    System.out.println(">> Response Time: "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - timeTrace));
.......
.......
.......
}
```

I appreciate any quick help and guidelines.

**Here is the error I get**

```
Mar 11, 2020 4:23:08 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute
WithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException) caught when processing
request: Connection reset
Mar 11, 2020 4:23:08 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute
WithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Mar 11, 2020 4:23:23 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute
WithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException) caught when processing
request: Connection reset
Mar 11, 2020 4:23:23 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute
WithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Mar 11, 2020 4:23:38 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute
WithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException) caught when processing
request: Connection reset
Mar 11, 2020 4:23:38 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute
WithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Connection reset
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:126)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.ja
va:321)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.ja
va:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.ja
va:259)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:137)

        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:11
52)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocke
tImpl.java:1063)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl
.java:402)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketIm
pl.java:716)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSoc
ketImpl.java:970)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStre
am.java:81)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.jav
a:142)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:15
3)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequ
estBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:502)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodB
ase.java:1973)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.j
ava:993)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(Htt
pMethodDirector.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMe
thodDirector.java:170)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.jav
a:396)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.jav
a:324)
        at af.aib.etl.AttendanceETL.fetchAndParseAttendanceRecord(AttendanceETL.
java:99)
        at af.aib.attendance.ApplicationStartPoint.main(ApplicationStartPoint.ja
va:28)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)

        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)

        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRe
cord.java:448)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInput
Record.java:165)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108)
```

Comment: Which exact Java version do you use for running the program? I had a similar problem with Java 11.0.3/4/5 only with 11.0.6 it worked without problems.

Comment: I have tried open JDK 11 and Java 8. I got the same result in both versions. I think it is not Java version issue.

Comment: For identifying SSL&TLS problems you should execute your test program on the non-working system using SSL debugging enabled: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659564

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local proxy and the server proxy were different that is why it was running fine on my local machine but not on the server, once I changed the proxy to the specific proxy which server was using then the application was working fine.