# Is there a way to determine the SSL/TLS version of an HTTP request with Karate DSL?

Tags: ssl, automation, karate

For a given request and response I would like to determine what version of TLS has been used, and if the request was secure, meaning that https was used.

I have tried using the karate.prevRequest but it is not working, responseHeaders does not have any information either and I have added '* configure ssl = true' in the background

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. There has never been a request to do this, so perhaps you can contribute code.

That said, if you know how to start the JVM and pass this system property, that might get you the information on the console: [limiting java ssl debug logging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23659564/143475)