# Proxy authentication with s_client

Tags: proxy, openssl, proxy-authentication

<sub>Note: this is not a duplicate of [openssl s_client using a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220419/openssl-s-client-using-a-proxy), as I am specifically interested in proxy authentication, not the ability to use proxy.</sub>

I'm using `openssl s_client` to inspect certificates of the target server to understand how/where the connection works or not. As I'm behind a corporate proxy, I can specify the proxy server with `-proxy` flag, however I need to pass authentication details (username/password) to this proxy - and I haven't figured out how to do that.

```
openssl s_client -proxy my.proxy.server:8080 -connect my.target.host
```

successfully connect to the proxy server, however, understandably, results in error `s_client: HTTP CONNECT failed: 407 Unauthorized`.

Passing proxy server in the form of `user:pass@my.proxy.server` or `http://user:pass@my.proxy.server` both result in error `s_client: -proxy argument malformed or ambiguous`.

How can I pass proxy authentication to s_client? I would find it hard to believe that it supports proxy but not authenticated proxy.

I'm using openssl version 1.1.1a.

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up on @Arnaud Grandville's answer: OpenSSL v3 beta 1 has now been released, and it includes proxy authentication options. You have to compile it yourself, however.

Unfortunately in v3 beta 1 the HTTP code had some issues so you can't use the code from their website as-is. Anyone looking to compile from source can use the commands below to get an OpenSSL installation with working proxy authentication:

```
git clone --branch openssl-3.0.0-beta1 https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
cd openssl
git fetch
git checkout 6a1f9cd -- crypto/http/http_client.c
./Configure
make
make install
```

**Edit**: For later versions this is no longer necessary as the bug was fixed. For example for version 3.0.5 you can simply run:

```
git clone --branch openssl-3.0.5 https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
cd openssl
./Configure
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape-from-intranet https://github.com/quaddy-services/escape-from-intranet#introduction

and specify

host=my.proxy.server
port=8080

in the app and use

```
openssl s_client -proxy localhost:3128 -connect my.target.host
```

and your local running application will enrich the real proxy call with your credentials.

(In case you have a transparent proxy you need to switch the default proxy decision to "PROXY" in the "Decision" Menu)

Answer (score 0):

openssl v3.0 will supports `proxy_user` and `proxy_pass` options.

no solution for now, the syntax after proxy is

```
 host + ':' + service
 host + ':' + '*'
 host + ':'
        ':' + service  
 '*'  + ':' + service
 host
 service
```

cf. [BIO_parse_hostserv](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/BIO_parse_hostserv.html)

Answer (score 0):

As of OpenSSL v3.2.0, you can do the following:

```
openssl s_client -proxy my.proxy.server:8080 -proxy_user user -proxy_pass pass:pass -connect my.target.host
```

Note the use of `pass:` prefix when specifying the passsword. This is to prevent the error `Invalid password argument, missing ':' within the first 5 chars`(see: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/19089#issuecomment-1230167594)