# Error while accessing visa.appiancloud.com (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In Jmeter I get the error while accessing https://visa.appiancloud.com

> nodename nor servname provided, or not known

I ran the same command in openssl:

> openssl s_client -connect visa.appiancloud.com:443 -showcerts
> getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
> connect:errno=0

Apart from this on my test URL there is a redirect to SSO

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue either using JMeter or OpenSSL

[image]

so my expectation is that your machine doesn't have direct connection to the Internet and you're sitting behind a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)

So you need to "tell" JMeter about this proxy server, the easiest way is adding the proxy information to the HTTP Request sampler's (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)) "Advanced" tab

[image]

alternatively you can use special JMeter's command-line options or *system.properties* file like it's described in [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) user manual chapter

The same applies to openssl, you need to [pass your proxy server via `-proxy` command-line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49170223/2897748)